# Get input from radio buttons wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

**Voila XML code**

---

```
<GroupBox x:Name="radioButtons">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton Content="Teacher" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Student" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

---

**cs file code**

---

```
private void save_data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    window2 win2 = new window2();

    //var type = sender as RadioButton;
    var type = radioButtons.Content;

    MessageBox.Show(type.ToString());// here when it displays " System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel "

    if (type.ToString().Length <= 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a type.");
    else
        win2.name.Text = type.ToString();

    win2.Show();
    //this.Close();
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use a private variable to maintain the selected radio button's content.
Add the Checked event to both the RadioButton, same event for both the radio buttons.

```
    private string radioContent = "";
    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var radio = (sender as RadioButton);
        radioContent = radio.Content.ToString();
    }
and on the save button click,

  private void save_data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   window2 win2 = new window2();

   MessageBox.Show(radioContent);// here when it displays " System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel "

  if (radioContent.Length <= 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a type.");
  else
    win2.name.Text = radioContent.ToString();

  win2.Show();
  //this.Close();
   }
```